# Ошибка (кодировки) при открытии файла html в python

Tags: python, html, url

Есть вот такой код:

```
r = requests.get(url)
with open('text.html', 'w') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.text)
```

На него выдаётся такая ошибка:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xb2' in position 5649: character maps to <undefined>`

Пытался сделать так:

```
with open('text.html', 'w', 'utf-8') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.text)
```

Выдаётся такая ошибка:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Пытался найти ответ на python.org - не нашёл

Comment: `open('text.html', 'w', encoding='cp1251')` Попробуйте

Comment: @Namerek ошибка как в 1

Comment: А `encoding='utf-8'` пробовали? `with open('text.html', 'w',encoding='utf-8') as output_file:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
r = requests.get(url)
with open('text.html', 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(r.content)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]